# C3P0 Data Pool JDBC URL is equals to null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

I am using Spring to manage my connection pool. whenever I run my app, I see this on the logs

```
Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@88f0b8ea [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@ce8fda44 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge0yw969iurgbvtwis0|6ee5f485, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 3000, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 300, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 15, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@ce2ef138 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge0yw969iurgbvtwis0|ccd341d, jdbcUrl -> null, properties -> {} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hge0yw969iurgbvtwis0|53eba4b8, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
```

There's a part there where  `jdbcUrl -> null` where I assume it's already null. However, I believe that I already have configured it here.

any ideas why it's returning a null?

```
   <bean id="clientDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/genesis_cms"/>
        <property name="user" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>



<bean id="clientDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/genesis_cms"/>
        <property name="user" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>


        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="clientDataSource"/>
            <property name="packagesToScan"  value = "org.myproject.package.commons.model.*"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.sql.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</prop>
                    <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">15</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
 <prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">SCHEMA</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">org.myproj.hibernate.SchemaResolver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">org.myproj.hibernate.MultitenantConnectionProvider</prop>

              </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id = "transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        </bean>
```

Exception message I am getting

```
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:89)
    at com.brightworks.genesis.client.config.hibernate.MultitenantConnectionProvider.getAnyConnection(MultitenantConnectionProvider.java:49)
    at com.brightworks.genesis.client.config.hibernate.MultitenantConnectionProvider.getConnection(MultitenantConnectionProvider.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$ContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:197)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:421)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:512)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.findByUsername(Unknown Source)
    at org.brightworks.genesis.commons.service.account.impl.AccountServiceImpl.findByUsername(AccountServiceImpl.java:25)
    at com.brightworks.genesis.client.webapp.controller.ProductController.addProductForm(ProductController.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at com.googlecode.webutilities.filters.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
```

Here's the multitenant connection provider

```
 public class MultitenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider, ServiceRegistryAwareService {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4368575201221677384L;

        private C3P0ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = null;

        @Override
        public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void injectServices(ServiceRegistryImplementor serviceRegistry) {
            Map lSettings = serviceRegistry.getService(ConfigurationService.class).getSettings();

            connectionProvider = new C3P0ConnectionProvider();
            connectionProvider.injectServices(serviceRegistry);
            connectionProvider.configure(lSettings);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class clazz) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
            final Connection connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
            return connection;
        }

        @Override
        public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
            final Connection connection = getAnyConnection();
            try {
                connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA '" + tenantIdentifier + "'");
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [" + tenantIdentifier + "]", e);
            }
            return connection;
        }

        @Override
        public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            try {
                connection.createStatement().execute("SET SCHEMA 'public'");
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new HibernateException("Could not alter JDBC connection to specified schema [public]", e);
            }
            connectionProvider.closeConnection(connection);
        }

        @Override
        public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            releaseAnyConnection(connection);
        }
    }

and My Schema Resolver

    public class SchemaResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

        @Override
        public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {

            return "tenant1"; //TODO: Implement service to identify tenant like: userService.getCurrentlyAuthUser().getTenantId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
            return false;
        }
```

and Schema Resolver

```
 public class SchemaResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {

        @Override
        public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {

            return "tenant1"; //TODO: Implement service to identify tenant like: userService.getCurrentlyAuthUser().getTenantId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get errors while creating a connection? Are there any error logs or exception traces? Btw spring is not managing your connection, hibernate is.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27338670/330315

Comment: As you have a spring managed datasource your `hibernate.c3p0` are useless and you shouldn't set the `hibernate.connection.*` properties as those interfere with the injected datasource.

Answer (score 1):

As you have a spring managed datasource your hibernate.c3p0 are useless and you shouldn't set the hibernate.connection.* properties as those interfere with the injected datasource. The properties for poolside etc. should be set on the `clientDataSource` bean instead.

```
<bean id="clientDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/genesis_cms"/>
    <property name="user" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${hibernate.connection.pool_size}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="300" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
</bean>
```

Another tip instead of setting some of the properties through `jpaProperties` use the `JpaVendorAdapter` instead. This would reduce your configuration of the `entityManagerFactory` to something like this.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="clientDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan"  value = "org.myproject.package.commons.model.*"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${hibernate.sql.dialect}" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

A final note, C3P0 isn't really maintained anymore, I would strongly suggest to use something like [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) instead.

Comment: You're correct, I managed to fix the issue with your given solution, however when I've added my multi-tenancy information/configuration that error still occur, I have updated my question. regarding that, please check.

Comment: Your own `MultitenantConnectionProvider` has a hard dependency on the c3po connection provider. Instead I guess you would have to use the `DataSourceConnectionProvider` and ideally not create one yourself but try to obtain the one used at config time.

Comment: If so, how would I do that?

Comment: You should be able to retrieve it by using `serviceRegistry.getService(ConnectionProvider.class)` instead of the `ConfigurationService.class`. It should already be configured and ready for use.